# How do I create a button that increments an attribute of a model and can be pressed once per browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, cookies, increment

An `apartment_listing` has many `reviews`, and a `review` belongs to an `apartment_listing`.

In the file `views/apartment_listings/show.html.erb`, I show a list of reviews for that particular `apartment_listing`. These reviews are generated with the partial view `apartment_listings/_review.html.erb` like so:

```
<%= render :partial => "review", :collection => @apartment_listing.reviews %>
```

In `_review`, I want to have a button that, when pressed:

1. Increments that review's `helpful_count` attribute.
2. Makes it so that it cannot be pressed again while in the same browser - probably using cookies.

I feel like the former shouldn't be too hard to figure out, but it's got me beat. I'm really not sure where to start with the second goal.

---

EDIT: I managed to update the review's `helpful_count` attribute with this code in `apartment_listings/_review.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for review, :method => :put, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :helpful_count, value: (review.helpful_count + 1) %    > 
  <%= f.submit 'Helpful?' %>
<% end %>
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, and I'd like to be able to disable the button after it is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for updating `helpful_count` has the potential for problems. Imagine two users have loaded an apartment on their web page. One of them marks it helpful, and the next one does as well. Since when they initially loaded the page, `helpful_count` was the same, after both of them click helpful, the count will only be incremented by one: it would be updated twice to the same value.

Really, you want to create a new action, probably under the reviews resource for an apartment. That action could use ActiveRecord's `increment` method to update the `helpful_count` (technically there's still a race condition in `increment!`, you'd encounter it much less often) http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21

Cookies seem like a reasonable solution for the latter problem. Simply bind to submit on the form with jQuery, and create the cookie in the handler.

Comment: I can definitely see what you're saying. I guess my main barrier to doing that is that I'm really not sure how to make a link that can call that method in reviews_controller on a particular review.

Comment: You need a new route in routes.rb to create the path helper, then do: link_to path_helper_goes_here, :remote => true

Answer (score 2):

What does the code look like in your `reviews` controller? More experienced RESTful coders might be able to speak more coherently on this, but the way I see it, incrementing the `helpful_count` attribute should be an action sent to the `reviews` controller. That way, you can create a link that performs the action asynchronously.

For example, inside _review.html.erb:

```
<% collection.each do |review| %>
<%= link_to "Mark as Helpful", "/apartment_listing/#{@apartment_listing.id}/reviews/#{@review.id}/incHelpful?nonce=#{SecureRandom.rand(16)}", :remote => true, :method => :put %>
# ... Do something cool with your review content ...
<% end %>
```

Inside your ReviewsController class:

```
def incHelpful
  unless params[:nonce] == session[:nonce][params[:id]]
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.helpful_count += 1
    @review.update_attributes(:helpful_count)
    session[:nonce][params[:id]] = params[:nonce]
  end
  render :nothing
  # Optionally return some javascript or JSON back to the browser on success/error
end
```

Inside /config/routes.rb:

```
put "apartment_listing/:apart_id/reviews/:id/incHelpful" => "reviews#incHelpful"
```

The main idea here is that actions that `edit` a resource should use the `PUT` http method, and that change should be handled by that resource's controller.  Rails' built-in AJAX functions are engaged by setting `:remote => true` inside the `link_to` helper. The second concept is that of a nonce, a random value that is only valid once. Once this value is set in the user's session, subsequent requests to `incHelpful` will do nothing.

Comment: I like your code, but it returned a `NoMethodError in Apartment_listings#show - private method `rand' called for SecureRandom:Module`

Comment: I replaced `rand` with `url safe_base64` and fixed that error, but now I get something really strange: undefined method `[]&#x27; for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, I was at work on a Windows machine, so I couldn't verify the code. The syntax is `SecureRandom.hex(16)`.

Comment: As far the as the "no [] for nil:NilClass" goes, you'll have to set up the :nonce key on the session variable once.  I'm not the best guy to ask how to do that, because I'm still learning Rails myself, and the `session` store is a bit of a mystery to me.  I think that you can set it up inside the `incHelpful` function one time per user like this:
    `def incHelpful
      if session[:nonce].nil?
       session[:nonce] = {}
      end
     # ...`

Comment: Man, this the errors just keep on coming. Now I'm getting this: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` for incHelpful

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to format comments. The `if` statement has to be on another line. You can't have anything after `def incHelpful` on that line. White space matters in Ruby.